# storing data into mysql in uppercase

Tags: php, mysql, database, wamp

how can I store my data in uppercase letter?

query

```
$personal_date_birth = checkDateY($personal_date_birth);

mysql_query("UPDATE personal_data SET personal_full_name = '".mysql_real_escape_string($personal_full_name)."', personal_title = '".mysql_real_escape_string($personal_title)."', personal_date_birth ='".mysql_real_escape_string($personal_date_birth)."', personal_marital_status = '".mysql_real_escape_string($personal_marital_status)."', personal_nationality = '".mysql_real_escape_string($personal_nationality)."', personal_race = '".mysql_real_escape_string($personal_race)."', personal_religion = '".mysql_real_escape_string($personal_religion)."', personal_gender = '".mysql_real_escape_string($personal_gender)."', personal_country_birth = '".mysql_real_escape_string($personal_country_birth)."', personal_bumiputra_status = '".mysql_real_escape_string($personal_bumiputra_status)."' WHERE LAS_login_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($LAS_login_id)."'")
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php

Comment: If you have MySQL 5.0, you could create an INSERT BEFORE trigger that
uppercases the columns values before storing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strtoupper()` function

Just Try this

```
$personal_date_birth = checkDateY($personal_date_birth); 
mysql_query("UPDATE personal_data SET 
personal_full_name='".mysql_real_escape_string(strtoupper($personal_full_name))."',
personal_title = '".mysql_real_escape_string(strtoupper($personal_title))."',
personal_date_birth ='".mysql_real_escape_string(strtoupper($personal_date_birth))."',
personal_marital_status = '".mysql_real_escape_string($personal_marital_status)."',
personal_nationality = '".mysql_real_escape_string(strtoupper($personal_nationality))."',
personal_race = '".mysql_real_escape_string(strtoupper($personal_race))."',
personal_religion = '".mysql_real_escape_string(strtoupper($personal_religion))."',
personal_gender = '".mysql_real_escape_string(strtoupper($personal_gender))."',
personal_country_birth = '".mysql_real_escape_string(strtoupper($personal_country_birth))."',
personal_bumiputra_status = '".mysql_real_escape_string(strtoupper($personal_bumiputra_status))."' 
WHERE LAS_login_id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($LAS_login_id)."'")
```

Comment: Im also doing in insert query. Its same way with update query?

Comment: btw, this is my insert query, $sql2="INSERT INTO family_child (LAS_login_id, family_child_type) VALUES ('$LAS_login_id', '$family_child_type')";

Comment: but im try doing like this (strtoupper('$family_child_type')), but it not working

Comment: `$sql2="INSERT INTO family_child (LAS_login_id, family_child_type) VALUES ('".strtoupper($LAS_login_id)."', '".strtoupper($family_child_type)."')";`

use this

Answer (score 2):

You should do it in php like Ankur said.
But you can also do it in MySQL using UPPER('string');

Answer (score 1):

Use "strtoupper()" function, put the text inside the brackets that you want as upper case.

Answer (score 1):

Use like below:

```
INSERT INTO `sample_table`(`name`) values(UPPER('new text'))
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this...

```
UPDATE products_description SET `products_name` = UPPER( `products_name` )
```